# Handling websocket client messages with aleph

Tags: clojure, websocket, aleph

During my quest to learn Clojure I am currently facing problems with setting up websocket communitation. After many different approaches, I ended up using [aleph](https://github.com/ztellman/aleph).

What I managed to achieve:

- handling of a new client connecting
- handling a client disconnection
- talking from the server to clients at will

What I lack is means to trigger a handler function whenever one of the connected clients sends something via the websocket.

My code so far:

```
(ns wonders7.core.handler
  (:require [compojure.core :refer :all]
            [compojure.route :as route]
            [ring.middleware.defaults :refer [wrap-defaults site-defaults]]
            [aleph.http :as http]
            [manifold.stream :as stream]
            [clojure.tools.logging :refer [info]]))

(defn uuid [] (str (java.util.UUID/randomUUID)))

(def clients (atom {}))

(defn ws-create-handler [req]
  (let [ws @(http/websocket-connection req)]
    (info "ws-create-handler")
    (stream/on-closed ws #(swap! clients dissoc ws))
    (swap! clients assoc ws (uuid))))

(defroutes app-routes
  (GET "/ws" [] ws-create-handler)
  (route/not-found "Not Found"))

(def app
  (wrap-defaults app-routes site-defaults))

(defn msg-to-client [[client-stream uuid]]
  (stream/put! client-stream "The server side says hello!"))

(defn msg-broadcast []
  (map #(msg-to-client %) @clients))

;(stream/take! (first (first @clients)))
;(http/start-server app {:port 8080})
```

I start the Netty server with the commented out http/start-server aleph call. I also managed to fetch messages from the client via manual stream/take! call (also commented out). What I need to figure out is how to trigger this taking automatically when something comes in.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The function you're looking for is `(manifold.stream/consume callback stream)`, which will invoke the callback for each message that comes off the stream.

Comment: One more question. Is it possible to send a message to the client from within a consume callback function body? This doesn't seem to work for me (nothing happens). On the other hand if I evaluate the sending code manually, the client receives it without any trouble.

Comment: Ok, figured that out. Was sending out messages by "mapping" the sending function to streams. Switching to doseq (which is intended for side effects) instead of mapping did the trick.

Answer (score 1):

in [This example](http://alexkehayias.tumblr.com/post/28783286946/a-simple-real-time-chat-server-using-clojure-and-aleph) the author uses `recieve-all` and `siphon` from aleph to accomplish a very similar task which I'll roughly paraphrase as:

```
(let [chat (named-channel room (receive-all ch #(println "message: " %)))]
  (siphon chat ch)
```